# Run apache Nutch 2.2.1

Tags: java, apache, web-crawler, nutch

I want to use the `Apache Nutch 2.2.1` for web page crawling. It has src file only. How would i run this. Is  there any tutorial available for that. I want the result as Json.  apache 1.6 is working perfectly in my system.

Please anybody can help me?

Comment: how are you planning to store your nutch data - gora, mysql or hbase?

Comment: I am going to use hbase

Comment: which version of hbase have you used?

Comment: which one did you use then?

Comment: I used nutch 2.1 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to follow this link http://nlp.solutions.asia/?p=362 but thats for Nutch 2.2 not 2.2.1. You can take a look at that link on atleast how to get started with a src file. Hope this helps!